# Php pdo insert array from form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, pdo

Through tutorial I created html form that inserts data into database. It works great, but in tutorial it is not explained why they use such code for array list.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test_user", "test123");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['btn-add']))
{
    $fields= (is_array($_POST['fields'])) ? $_POST['fields'] : array();
    $insertStmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (test_field) VALUES (:field)");

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $insertStmt->execute(array('field' => $field));
    }
}

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>field 1 <input type="text" name="fields[0]"></label>         
    <label>field 2 <input type="text" name="fields[1]"></label>
    <button type="submit" name="btn-add">add</button>
</form>
```

My question is about this line. Maybe someone could explain it.

```
$products = (is_array($_POST['fields'])) ? $_POST['fields'] : array();
```

What this line do -  **? $_POST['fields'] : array();**

Why it does not work just with **$products = (is_array($_POST['fields']))**

Also is this a good way to create array insert from form or I should search for different tutorial?

Comment: It's called a *ternary operator* - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary -- just doing `is_array($_POST['fields'])` would return a boolean true/false, not a value/array.

Comment: IF `is_array($_POST['fields'])` is equal to TRUE then set `$products` equal to `$_POST['fields']` or FALSE,  `$products` is equal to `array()` - Ternary Operator

Comment: As Qirel wrote. I would just add that your solution would assign `true` or `false` (so boolean) to the `products` variable, depending on the type of the `_POST['fields']` variable, but you need an array there, not boolean. Which is what the original line is doing - it assigns there the content of `_POST['fields']` if it's an array or an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fields = (is_array($_POST['fields'])) ? $_POST['fields'] : array();
```

**Explanation**

If `$_POST['fields']` is an array, the condition evaluates to `true`. If the condition is true, the expression `$_POST['fields']` before `:` will be assigned to the variable `$fields` otherwise the expression `array()` after `:` will be assigned.

The syntax goes like:

```
$var = condition ? expr1 : expr2;
```

To make you more clear, here it is:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 20;    
$c = $b > $a ? $b : $a;
```

Here, we check the condition if `$b` is greater than `$a`, if it is true, `$b`'s value is assigned to `$c`, if it is false, `$a`'s value is assigned.

This is how ternary expression works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything makes much more sense now!

Comment: Glad that I made you more clear about ternary expression and you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

The line you mentioned sets the variable `$products` to an array, no matter if there are data is given via the form or not.

```
$products = (is_array($_POST['fields'])) ? $_POST['fields'] : array();
```

says "If `$_POST['fields']` is an array, then set `$products` to this given array, otherwise set `$products` as an empty array".

For further information on the ternary operator you can have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

This ensures, that the following code

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $insertStmt->execute(array('field' => $field));
}
```

doesn't raise a Warning like

```
WARNING Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line number ...
```

Hope this helps :)